# How would I go about detecting when a slide is created using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to know a way to run specific code when a slide is created.

I would also like to know if there is a way to create an animation (when it triggers, then code runs) and a transition. That could have been put in another question, but I don't know if there is a rate limit or something.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like Google Slides has no `onEdit` trigger capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

#### Sadly, there is no direct way of detecting whether a slide has been created or not as there are no triggers for this.

However, as a workaround you can create a time-based trigger which runs at the time frame you choose and constantly checks the numbers of slides of the presentation.

```js
function slideNumber() {
  let presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  let slides = presentation.getSlides();
  return slides.length;
}

function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('checkSlides')
       .timeBased()
       .everyHours(6)
       .create();
}

function checkSlides() {
  let currentSlideNumber = slideNumber();
  // other instructions
}
```

Moreover, if you would like to have a trigger implemented for this specific action in Apps Script, I suggest you to file a **feature request** on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113&pli=1).

As for triggering a code after an animation has run, this is cannot be done either. The only way around this is to create a time trigger again and eventually see when to run it.

It is also important to note that setting and getting animations through Apps Script is not possible.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).